# How to map List of nested objects in Spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to map Nested objects in Spring data elasticsearch

I have object 1 having list of object 2. How to efficiently map this so that querying back elasticsearch is easy ? I want to retrieve object 2 based on ID.

```
@Document(indexName = xxx, type = xxx)
public class Object1 {
    private List<Obj2> lstObj2;
} 

public class Obj2 {

    private Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nested Object` like this:

```java
@Document(indexName = xxx, type = xxx)
public class Object1 {

  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
  private List<Obj2> lstObj2;
} 

public class Obj2 {
  private Long id;
}
```

As per your requirement it seems that you can use `inner Object` as well. Use `inner object` like this.

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Object)
private List<Obj2> lstObj2;
```

Comment: Without marking it as object I could query these values. What is special about Nested or Inner Object compared to normal mapping

Comment: This is same as Mapping which you provide while creating an index using ES.

Comment: @Richa why am i getting reason=failed to parse field